# Hide <li> when window resized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, hidden

I have a navigation bar at the top of the screen

- Aligned to the left are links which are placed inside li elements
- And aligned to the right is a search box

When the window is full screen both the links and search box sit nicely with a gap in the middle. But when the window is resized and the search box touches the right most li element, the search box will then drop to the next line.

Instead of dropping to the next line i would like to make the right most li element disappear when the window is re-sized. And as the window is resized further, more li elements disappear (from the right), i hope that makes sense.

I tried using

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

but its not working, here is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/preetz86/utyhf9hj/

Comment: Have you tried Media Queries?

Comment: I don't see a search box and any `<li>`'s

Comment: @Morpheus Sorry the fiddle didnt save, i updated the link

Comment: You can use `hidden-xs` class to hide the search on mobile or `hidden-sm` on tablet. https://jsfiddle.net/utyhf9hj/1/

Comment: @Morpheus I dont think that would work because i need to make the right most li disappear as the window is being resized. So if you look at my fiddle, item 13 is first to be hidden then, item 12 and so on, as the window is resized.

Comment: Here's an example that may help: http://bootply.com/1611Wpi4wF

Comment: @Skelly unfortunately that changes all li elements when the window is resized, i need to just remove the right most li when it touches the search box.

Comment: Something like that -> https://jsfiddle.net/utyhf9hj/3/, but you will end up by having to define all widths manually. Another option is to use javascript,

Comment: @Morpheus thats what i need, any idea on how to do it using js?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use `@media` :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { /* 640 for example */
    .li {
        display : none;
    }
}
```

Another alternative could be to simply use `white-space : nowrap` CSS proprety to tell you stylesheet to not drop element in line below. Use this proprety on the container of your element containing the list and the search bar.

Comment: i tried it in the fiddle and it didnt work, just to be clear im trying to make the right most li disappear as the window is resized. So if you look at my fiddle, `item 13` is to be hidden then `item 12` and so on, as the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `jQuery` and `@media`

```
$(function ()
{
    var width_before_links = $('.navbar-header').width() + $('#menu_items').width();
    var width_of_each_li = $('.recently-viewed li').width();
    var gap = 15;
    var width_after_links = $('.navbar-right').width();
    var current_link = 1;
    var max_width_style = "<style>";

    while ( current_link <= {{ count( Session::get( 'recently_viewed' )) }} )
    {
        max_width = width_before_links + ( width_of_each_li * current_link ) + gap + width_after_links;

        max_width_style = max_width_style
        + "@media screen and (max-width: " + max_width + "px) {" +
            ".recently-viewed li:nth-child(" + current_link + ") {" +
             "display : none;" +
            "}" +
          "}";

         current_link++;
    }
    $( max_width_style + "</style>" ).appendTo( "head" );
});
```